# JISON: How do I avoid "dog" being parsed as "do"?

Tags: jison

I have the following JISON file (lite version of my actual file, but reproduces my problem):

```
%lex

%%

"do"                        return 'DO';
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*      return 'ID';
"::"                        return 'DOUBLECOLON'
<<EOF>>                     return 'ENDOFFILE';

/lex

%%

start
    : ID DOUBLECOLON ID ENDOFFILE
    {$$ = {type: "enumval", enum: $1, val: $3}}
    ;
```

It is for parsing something like "AnimalTypes::cat". It works fine for things like "AnimalTypes::cat", but the when it sees dog instead of cat, it asumes it's a DO instead of an id. I can see why it does that, but how do I get around it? I've been looking at other JISON documents, but can't seem to spot the difference that (I assume) makes those work.

This is the error I get:

```
JisonParserError: Parse error on line 1:
PetTypes::dog
----------^
Expecting "ID", "enumstr", "id", got unexpected "DO"
```

Repro steps:

1. Install jison-gho globally from npm (or modify code to use local version). I use Node v14.6.0.
2. Save the JISON above as `minimal-repro.jison`
3. Run: `jison -m es -o ./minimal.mjs ./minimal-repro.jison` to create parser
4. Create a file named `test.mjs` with code like:

```
import Parser from "./minimal.mjs";
Parser.parser.parse("PetTypes::dog")
```

5. Run `node test.mjs`

Edit: Updated with a reproducible example.
Edit2: Simpler JISON

Comment: Please create a [mre] and edit it into your question. Also, specify which jison you are using; sadly, it makes a difference. We need a complete reproducible example because otherwise there's a lot of speculation necessary. (For example, I speculate that you supplied a particular option, but maybe you just typed `do` differently in your actual jison file.) The lexer options are important in this case

Comment: @rici I've updated it with a complete jison file to reproduce my problem and info regarding my environment (see repro steps).

Comment: If you remove the "DO" rule, does it match properly? How about not using a definition  and writing the `id` regex explicitly? Dog is longer than "Do", so it should match. unrelated, note that if you actually had an `enum::do`, it would break on your pattern matching (you would need to swap the rule order).

Comment: @kabanus If I remove ```"do" return 'DO';```, then it works fine. I do however need it to match do-while loops. I'm guessing that the same issue would arise with while-loops, variable names etc. I just tried replacing ```{id}``` with the regex, but it didn't change anything. If I swap the order of ```id``` and ```do```, then everything would be an id :( What I really don't understand is, that this is pretty basic stuff. In eg. java, I should be able to create a variable named ```doesThisWork```, so there must be something I'm missing...

Comment: The Flex pattern matching rules (which Jison) is based on explicitly say the pattern with the longest match is used, and only in case of a tie is the first one used. This seems like a bug as is. Try and get rid of everything except these two patterns, maybe even user code. That would be super minimal, and if that breaks, you found a bug I think.

Comment: @kabanus I've just made it as small as I can (see updated JISON) and it still fails with the same error :(

Comment: I would [open a bug](https://github.com/zaach/jison/issues) with this minimal example. Flex rules say Dog should match before do.

Comment: @kabanus Thanks. I've opened the following bug at the jison-gho repo, as it doesn't seem to be an issue with the jison package that it is based on. https://github.com/GerHobbelt/jison/issues/62

Comment: @kabanus: "it's not a bug, it's a feature"  :-)  See https://github.com/zaach/jison/issues/63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike (f)lex, the jison lexer accepts the first matching pattern, even if it is not the longest matching pattern. You can get the (f)lex behaviour by using

```
 %option flex
```

However, that significantly slows down the scanner.

The original jison automatically added `\b` to the end of patterns which ended with a literal string matching an alphabetic character, to make it easier to match keywords without incurring this overhead. In jison-gho, this feature was turned off unless you specify

```
 %option easy_keyword_rules
```

See https://github.com/zaach/jison/wiki/Deviations-From-Flex-Bison#user-content-literal-tokens.

So either of those options will achieve the behaviour you expect.